# Installing cassandra-tools for Cassandra 3.1

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

It is possible to install Cassandra tools for Cassandra 3.0 from the Datastax repo using

```
yum install cassandra30-tools
```

However, this doesn't work for Cassandra 3.1, and cassandra31-tools doesn't exist.  Are the tools available for Cassandra 3.1?